# Set java custom location in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, testing, jenkins, pom.xml

I run my tests in Jenkins on the server using Maven project.

The default path to java on the server is 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java

Instead, I would like to use java 1.8 in my tests and it is located in:

/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

How can I set this in jenkins properties or in a POM file so maven will use java 1.8 instead of default one?

I tried to set a String property JAVA_HOME or to set the path to jdk 8 in MAVEN_OPTS but it still uses default java.

Comment: In the Build Environment of your project you can set JAVA_HOME to your version of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solution is to declare the JDK8 installation on your Jenkins master server configuration:

[image]

And next, use this JDK8 config in your Jenkins job:

[image]

You can do the same in the node configuration screen:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding But I can't find these settings in my node configuration. And even "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" phrase is absent. Some permission issue?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for the node configuration. Please confirm it solves your pb :)

Comment: yes, it helped to set a custom java location, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. pom.xml:

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <verbose>true</verbose>
             <fork>true</fork>
             <executable>${jdk}/bin/javac</executable>
             <compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <jvm>${jdk}/bin/java</jvm>
             <forkMode>once</forkMode>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>

     <profiles>
         <profile>
         <id>default_jdk</id>
         <activation>
             <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <properties>
             <jdk>${env.JAVA_HOME}</jdk>
         </properties>
       </profile>
       <profile>
         <id>jdk8</id>
         <activation>
             <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <properties>
             <jdk>/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64</jdk>
         </properties>
       </profile>    
     </profiles>
   ```
2. Activate profile jdk8:

   ```
   mvn clean install -Pjdk8
   ```

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems like Jenkins starts VM before setting Maven. This is what I see in the console: 

`[selenium] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=786M -Dgwt.compiler.localWorkers=1 -XshowSettings:vm 

VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size: 1.00G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM`

And then: 
`Executing Maven:  

-B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TWO033-selenium-tests-forked-repository/test/selenium/pom.xml test site -Pjdk8`